# Websocket session is not being persisted in JDBC session store type

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-websocket, spring-session

Problem: WebSocker session data are not persisted in precreated session tables (SPRING_SESSION, SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES)

I followed this guide to implement it https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/web-socket.html

I´m using Spring Boot 2.7.6, Java 11

Spring related dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

App properties:

```
spring:
  session:
    store-type: jdbc
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=LEGACY
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: password
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: true
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    change-log: liquibase/db.changelog-master.yaml
```

WebSocket config:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.session.Session;
import org.springframework.session.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer<Session> {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/reservation");
        registry.addEndpoint("/reservation").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

WebSocket Controller impl:

```
import cz.reservation.app.ErrorCode;
import cz.reservation.app.model.WsRequest;
import cz.reservation.app.model.dto.ReservableScheduleDto;
import cz.reservation.app.service.ReservationService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class ReservableScheduleWebSocketController {

    @Autowired
    private ReservationService reservationService;

    @MessageMapping("/reservation")
    @SendTo("/topic/reservable-schedule")
    public ReservableScheduleDto wsRequestHandle(WsRequest wsRequest) throws Exception {

        ...some logic

    }

}
```

I checked in a browser that SESSION cookie is created when conneting with websocket.

I expect that Spring Boot will ensure that WebSocket session will be also stored in pregenerated SPRING_SESSION table (not only in a browser). What could be wrong with my code? Thank you!